# How to fix certificate error in go language " x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"

Tags: go

I am using this command to import library `go mod tidy`
but I am getting this error:

```
go: downloading github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 v1.9.0
go: downloading github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql v1.4.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/exp v0.0.0-20191002040644-a1355ae1e2c3
go: downloading gonum.org/v1/netlib v0.0.0-20190313105609-8cb42192e0e0
ki/distance imports
        gonum.org/v1/gonum/mat tested by
        gonum.org/v1/gonum/mat.test imports
        golang.org/x/exp/rand: golang.org/x/exp@v0.0.0-20191002040644-a1355ae1e2c3: Get https://proxy.golang.org/golang.org/x/exp/@v/v0.0.0-20191002040644-a1355ae1e2c3.zip: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
ki/distance imports
        gonum.org/v1/gonum/mat tested by
        gonum.org/v1/gonum/mat.test imports
        gonum.org/v1/netlib/blas/netlib: gonum.org/v1/netlib@v0.0.0-20190313105609-8cb42192e0e0: Get https://proxy.golang.org/gonum.org/v1/netlib/@v/v0.0.0-20190313105609-8cb42192e0e0.zip: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

My `go.mod` look like this :

```
module ki

go 1.13

require (
    github.com/gorilla/handlers v1.5.1
    github.com/gorilla/mux v1.8.0
    github.com/lib/pq v1.10.2
    gonum.org/v1/gonum v0.9.1
)
```

However I have tried to update my ca-certificates also by using `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ca-certificates && sudo update-ca-certificates` but the error remains same. I have also tried to downgrade my go version from 1.16 to 1.13 but the error still appears. The same program is working fine on my colleague machine but only my machine is facing this error. I have also tried to add `-insecure` switch to `go mod tidy -insecure` but it did not work.

I have also tried downloading the libraries manually by using the `go get --insecure gonum.org/v1/gonum/mat` (with and without insecure switch) and getting similar error.

```
go get gonum.org/v1/gonum/mat: module gonum.org/v1/gonum/mat: Get https://proxy.golang.org/gonum.org/v1/gonum/mat/@v/list: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I have noticed that all the certificates error are linked to `@v/list` if that can be of any help.

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy or VPN?

Comment: @RamarajaRamanujan Yes, I am using VPN, but the issue was resolved when I am running `go mod tidy` in **Windows PowerShell** instead of **Ubuntu Wsl**.